# Updating store with the response from client.query with react-apollo for a searchbar function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a Graphcool backend that I would like to search through when hit a button. To my understanding: If I use the graphql container from `react-apollo`, a component will instantly make a query once mounted.

This is not what I want. I intend to search only when a button is pressed. I'm aware that the withApollo container allows me to make a query like so:

```
this.props.client.query({
        query: MY_QUERY,
        variables: {
            first, // for pagination
            skip,
            orderBy,
            searchText
        }
    }); // returns a promise
```

My question: How do I update the store with the response it returns? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I realized I was going about this the wrong way. I found this helpful post: [search feature with react-apollo](https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/blob/master/content/frontend/react-apollo/7-filtering-searching-the-list-of-links.md).

I would be simpler to have state and then update said state with the response like so:

```
this.props.client.query({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    variables: {
        first, // for pagination
        skip,
        orderBy,
        searchText
    },
}).then(result => this.setState({ thingsToRender: result.data.thingsToRender });
```

Then you would of course render the objects by mapping over it or using a FlatList (if you're using react native).

I also found out how to update my store if I really wanted to do it that way. The component will need to be wrapped by both `graphql` and `withApollo` higher-order components from `react-apollo` for this to work :

```
compose(
  withApollo,
  graphql(SOME_QUERY)
)(MyComponent)
```

you then make a method like so:

```
onSearchButtonPress = async () => {
  const { first, skip, orderBy, searchText } = this.state;

  const result = await this.props.client.query({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    variables: {
      first,
      skip,
      orderBy,
      searchText
    }
  });
  const items = result.data.items;
  this.props.data.updateQuery(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    allItems: _.uniqBy([...prev.allItems, ...items], o => o.id)
    // lodash uniqBy helper method helps with removing older items
    // with the same id (essentially updating them)
  });
```

It's almost like updating state in a redux reducer.